# "empty cache and hard reload" equivalent in ie?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, google-chrome-devtools

When I have Chrome Dev Tools open I can right-click the refresh button in the browser address bar and select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" from the context menu.  This is a useful way to ensure that all client side files have been refreshed and reflect my latest changes.  I'm currently testing some functionality in IE and I'm trying to figure out the equivalent action. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Press Ctrl+f5 keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold the Ctrl key and press the F5 key Or hold the Ctrl key and click the Refresh button.

for empty cache you can try steps: https://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page

Comment: This will not empty the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to empty the cache, beyond the basic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click refresh, this guide can help: http://refreshyourcache.com/en/internet-explorer-10/.